# apply css style in HTML usin jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list in HTML with id of 'nav'. I want to apply CSS style to it using jQuery. How do I  do it. I have tried couple of things and failed. Please help. I am new to jQuery and learning the basics now. thanks

Comment: What does your HTML markup look like and what have you tried so far that failed?

Comment: Show us what you did and failed with. It's easier to help when we have code in front of us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***You can do the following:***

`$('li#nav').css('background','green');`

`$('li#nav')` selects the list element. Then `.css('background','green')` applys green background to the li element.

***Or you can do this:***

Create a CSS class in your CSS file with a class

```
.list-style{
   backbround : Green;
}
```

then in your jQuery write following:

`$('li#nav').addClass('list-style');`

Answer (score 1):

Have you at least seen the manual? There are examples there: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Single style */
    $('#nav').css('property','value');

    /* Multiple styles */
    $('#nav').css({'property1':'value1', 'property2':'value2', ...});
});
```

You can read more about CSS and Jquery here - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) jQuery function to get/set style rules to an element or a group of elements. Example:

```
$("#myDiv").css("display", "none");
$("input#myButton").css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not that hard ;)

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="navi" style="color: black">
    HALLO
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navi").css("color", "red")
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

- [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rmTTe/)
- [Jquery reference](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Did you intend the two links to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax

```
$('#nav').css('background','black');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS method

```
 $("#nav").css("color","red");
```

If you have a css class with some style definition, you may use the addClass method

```
$("#nav").addClass("myCSSStyle")
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/WRYKB/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
<ul id="nav2">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){   
    $("#nav").css("color","red");    //setting css property to element
    $("#nav2").addClass("myCSSStyle")  //applying css class
});
```

**CSS**

```
.myCSSStyle
{
  color:blue;
   font-weight:bold; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to your nav like this

```
$("#nav").addClass("myClass yourClass");
```

For more info you can refer http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0):

From the API documentation (which you SHOULD have read)

```
$("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");
```

> This method is often used with .removeClass() to switch elements'
>   classes from one to another, like so:

```
$("p").removeClass("myClass noClass").addClass("yourClass");
```